# want to run c program from php using exec() function

Tags: php, c

i'm trying to run one c executable file using php `exec()`.

When c contains a simple program like `print hello`. I'm using

```
exec('./print.out')
```

It's working fine. But when I need to pass a argument to my c program I'm using

```
exec('./arugment.out -n 1234')
```

It is not working. Can any body tell me how to pass arugment using `exec` to c program.

Comment: Any output from `./argument.out -n 1234` execution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From taking a look at the php documentation, it appears that `exec` treats arguments a bit oddly. You could try doing

```
exec("./argument.out '-n 1234'")
```

to prevent it from mangling them (it normally separates them all on space, which might be what's messing it up).

Comment: So if I'd like to pass 2 arguments I should do `exec("./argument.out '-n 1234 -o 5678'")` or `exec("./argument.out '-n 1234' '-o 5678'")` ?

Comment: when i m trying to run exec("./a.out '-n 1234'") i m getting error:bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"./a.out '-n 1234'"'